# Prevent uninstalling phpmyadmin when uninstalling php

Tags: php, uninstall, yum, centos-6

I have a centos 6 server and i want to upgrade my php version from 5.4 to 5.5 but as far as i know i need to uninstall version 5.4 first (most guides say so at least), when i type `yum remove php-common` though it says it will remove squirrelmail and phpMyAdmin too.
I don't want this to happen, is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing packages using rpm and the --nodeps option as explained here: https://ma.ttias.be/removing-a-package-without-its-dependencies-in-centos-or-rhel/

```
rpm -qa | grep "php-sqlite2" #lists packages with this name
php-sqlite2-5.1.6-200705230937
rpm -e --nodeps "php-sqlite2-5.1.6-200705230937" #remove package without dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you see the warning at your link?

> Please note: you do this at your own risk. You usually just make the dependency hell bigger. Please contact a seasoned Linux Sysadmin to help you with this..

`rpm -e --nodeps` should be reserved as a last resort.  If you want to swap packages without upsetting other packages that depend on what they provide, you can use `yum shell`, `yum swap`, or `yum replace` (available via the yum-plugin-replace package) to remove and install packages in a single transaction.

It isn't clear from your question where you are getting PHP 5.4 for CentOS 6, but I would be cautious with repositories that override stock packages names.  It is common practice when deviating from stock versions to use a version suffix on the package name, such as `php55` or similar.